# Partial duplicates in r

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, duplicates

I am working with a big dataframe, that looks like this one

```
             X V1 V2 V3
1 IOJRE.no.m-1 10  2  0
2 IOJRE.no.m-2 10  7  0
3 OHIJR.no.m-4  5  5  1
4 OHIJR.no.m-6  5  6  1
5 OHIJR.no.m-3  3  3  1
6 OHIJR.no.m-1  2  3  1
7 ABCDE.no.m-1  5  6  0
8 ABCDE.no.m-5  1  4  0

> dput(mydata)
structure(list(X = structure(c(3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("ABCDE.no.m-1", "ABCDE.no.m-5", "IOJRE.no.m-1", 
"IOJRE.no.m-2", "OHIJR.no.m-1", "OHIJR.no.m-3", "OHIJR.no.m-4", 
"OHIJR.no.m-6"), class = "factor"), V1 = c(10, 10, 5, 5, 3, 2, 
5, 1), V2 = c(2, 7, 5, 6, 3, 3, 6, 4), V3 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0)), .Names = c("X", "V1", "V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, 
8L), class = "data.frame")
```

The first 5 letters in many items in the first column are similar. I am trying to subset the data, keeping only one of these similar items, which has the highest V1 value. (if the V1 value is the same, it doesn't matter which one to keep for me).

I cannot think of a proper command because this is not a `duplicated()`. I thought of using `aggregate()` then `which.max()` But I really cannot construct a proper command for the job.
Here's the output I am looking to have.

```
             X V1 V2 V3
1 IOJRE.no.m-1 10  2  0
2 OHIJR.no.m-4  5  5  1
3 ABCDE.no.m-1  5  6  0


> dput(mydata2)
structure(list(X = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("ABCDE.no.m-1", 
"IOJRE.no.m-1", "OHIJR.no.m-4"), class = "factor"), V1 = c(10L, 
5L, 5L), V2 = c(2L, 5L, 6L), V3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("X", 
"V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a data.table approach (probably not the best, but it works and is fast)

```
library("data.table")
mydata <- data.table(mydata)
mydata[,X:=strtrim(X,5)]
setkey(mydata,X,V1)
mydata[unique(X),mult="last"]

       X V1 V2 V3
1: ABCDE  5  6  0
2: IOJRE 10  7  0
3: OHIJR  5  6  1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems like I do not have these functions installed into my R yet. Sorry I could not apply the command you posted above.

Comment: install.packages("data.table"), that's all

Comment: Ah I did not realise data.table was the package name. I am on it :) thanks

Comment: you're welcome. it'll be pretty fast compared to Asayats answer

Comment: WoW Yes! a couple of seconds! That was very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the fastest way to do that, but it answers your question :)

1) Substring your 1st variable:

```
substr(x$X,1,5)
```

2) Find max value for each group of substring

```
y <- lapply(split(x, substr(x$X,1,5)), function(x) {
x[which.max(x$V1),]})
```

3) Create new dataframe from results:

```
do.call(rbind, y)
```

Comment: Hi Asayat, the command is working fine, but it is taking forever to do the calculation. But it is eventually working. Cheers.